# Session Issue with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I seem to be having a problem when applying a user to a session. When I login, the function runs perfect and bcrypt check the password perfectly. But when the `req.session.user = user` is called I get `Cannot set property user of undefined`.

Here is my users.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
router.use(expressValidator);
var UserModel = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});


router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.registerUser = function(req,res){

  console.warn('Getting Here');
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

  console.log(req.body.name);

  var newUser = new UserModel({
    name:name,
    email:email,
    username:username,
    password: password
  });

  UserModel.createUser(newUser, function(err,user){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(user);
  });

}

router.login = function(req,res){


    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;


    UserModel.findById("584340be3f63a303484eccc0", function(err, user){


        console.warn(user.username);
        console.warn(user.password);

        bcrypt.compare(password , user.password, function(err,res) {
            if (err) throw err;


        });

        console.warn (user);
        req.session.user = user;
        console.warn(req.session.user);

    })




}






module.exports = router;
```

As you can see in the file im finding a user in the DB and comparing its string. If the strings are correct I just want to add the user to the session. Here is my app.js file where the middleware is housed.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var candidates = require('./routes/candidates.js');
var supporters = require('./routes/supporters.js');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/candidates', candidates.findAll);
app.get('/candidates/:id', candidates.findOne);
app.put('/candidates/:id/votes', candidates.incrementUpvotes);
app.delete('/candidates/:id', candidates.deleteCandidate);

app.get('/supporters', supporters.findAll);
app.get('/supporters/:id', supporters.findOne);
app.post('/supporters',supporters.addPerson);
app.post('/candidates', candidates.addPerson);
app.post('/candidates/:id',candidates.updateCandidate);
app.post('/image',candidates.addImage);
app.post('/register', users.registerUser);
app.post('/login', users.login);

app.delete('/supporters/:id', supporters.deleteSupporter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(expressValidator({
        errorFormatter: function(param,msg,value){
            var namespace = param.split('.'),
                root = namespace.shift(),
                formParam = root;

            while(namespace.length){
                formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
            }
            return{
                param: formParam,
                msg: msg,
                value: value

            };
        }
    }
));

//Connect Flash

app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});




module.exports = app;
```

I've been at this problem for quite a while now and was wondering if anyone can send me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get rid of all the code that is not relevant to session. So strip your code as much as possible and come back again and rephrase your question with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In app.js I had some of my app.use functions placed below the app.user('router') and it was causing the issue